# Set all boolean objects to false in generic list java?

Tags: java, list, boolean

I have a list of following type

```
public class Tag{
 boolean selected;

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
String title;
String id;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

Created list as follows

```
List<Tag> brandList = new ArrayList<>();
 brandList.add(new Tag("1","A",false));
    brandList.add(new Tag("2","v",true));
    brandList.add(new Tag("3","f",false));
    brandList.add(new Tag("4","g",true));
    brandList.add(new Tag("5","y",true));
    brandList.add(new Tag("6","e",true));
    brandList.add(new Tag("7","r",false));
    brandList.add(new Tag("18","y",true));
    brandList.add(new Tag("16","j",true));
    brandList.add(new Tag("19","m",false));
```

I want to set all values of selected object in list to false without looping through the list.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: and ... why don't you want to iterate over the list?

Comment: @Stultuske this is just limited data and the actual list can contain 600-700 objects

Comment: 600-700 objects is nothing.

Comment: @Wishy so? do you think the amount of code you need to write in a loop is dependent on the number of elements?

Comment: You could of course copy the following code 600 times: `list.get(n++).setSelected(false)` where `n` is initially `int n = 0`

Comment: You can always write `brandList.get(0).setSelected(false); brandList.get(1).setSelected(false); [...] brandList.get(list.size()-1).setSelected(false);` but that looks like calling for some kind of loop/iteration.

Comment: Anyway your question looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Maybe it would be worth describing *actual* problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do it without iterating. If you want to avoid a traditional loop, you can still use `forEach`:

```
brandList.forEach(brand -> brand.setSelected(false));
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll obviously need to iterate through the list. There is no memory set mechanism that will allow that kind of subtlety, especially considering the objects are not stored near each other.

But if you just don't want to write it yourself, use forEach():

```
brandList.forEach(tag -> tag.setSelected(false));
```

Comment: When using an array backed list the references *are* stored next to each other, but this doesn't solve the problem either

Comment: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): java.util.ArrayList#forEach

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do want you want without iterating on each object.

**PLEASE NOTE** : this is a dirty, hacky and rather complex way. If implemented, you should only access your `selected` value through `isSelected()` (which is a general requirement of encapsulation).

**You should really iterate on it, but I give you a "solution" for the sake of the experiment.**

---

Now that I've put the disclaimers first:

### Attribute them a global switch

Create an object "Switch" that you can give to all of them, the class should look like:

```
class Switch {
    private boolean switchedOff = false;
    private LocalDateTime lastSwitchOff;

    public boolean isSwitchedOff() {
        return switchedOff;
    }

    public void switchOff() {
        switchedOff = true;
        lastSwitchOff = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLastSwitchOff() {
        return lastSwitchOff;
    }
}
```

Once your switch is switchedOff, all of the `isSelected()` calls of you `Tag` object will return false, unless you set them again. This is how you add it to your `Tag` class:

```
public class Tag {
    private final String title;
    private final String id;
    private boolean selected;
    private Switch theSwitch;
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        if (theSwitch != null && theSwitch.isSwitchedOff() &&  lastModified.isBefore(theSwitch.getLastSwitchOff())) return false;
        else return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        lastModified = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public Tag(String id, String title, boolean selected, Switch theSwitch) {
        lastModified = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.selected = selected;
        this.theSwitch = theSwitch;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then you can use it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Switch mySwitch = new Switch();
    List<Tag> brandList = new ArrayList<>();
    brandList.add(new Tag("1", "A", false, mySwitch));
    brandList.add(new Tag("2", "v", true, mySwitch));
    brandList.add(new Tag("3", "f", false, mySwitch));
    brandList.add(new Tag("4", "g", true, mySwitch));
    brandList.add(new Tag("5", "y", true, mySwitch));
    brandList.add(new Tag("18", "y", true, mySwitch));
    brandList.add(new Tag("16", "j", true, mySwitch));
    brandList.add(new Tag("19", "m", false, mySwitch));

    mySwitch.switchOff();

    // Now all of the isSelected() calls will return false 
}
```

Comment: Why not introducing a `switchOn` method, this would remove the limitation of only using it once?

Comment: What would the `switchOn` method do? Give them all back their previous value before the `switchOff `? If your question is more "why can't we do it several times"  it's because once you've called `setSelected` and the switch is off how do you know which happened last? The switchedOf or the setSelected? I'm still thinking about this issue, I see a solution with comparing timeStamps but it makes it even more complicated

Comment: As per my understanding of your proposed solution it should be quite easy to switch it back on, as you don't discard the `selected` property, but rather hide it (by just returning `false` always)

Comment: I added the time fields to be able to use it several times, but IMO the `switchOn` method is not needed because it's not in OP's requirements

Answer (score 0):

You're working from a false premise here:

> @Stultuske this is just limited data and the actual list can contain 600-700 objects

You can loop over a few hundred thousand objects and very likely not even hit more than a second or two of CPU time. As one of the commenters said, "600-700 is nothing."

With that said, this is the best way to do it if raw speed is what you want:

```
for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
    Tag x = list.get(index);
    x.setBooleanValue(false);
}
```

Primitive loops are better than "foreach" (for x in y or forEach) because there is no method being called per iteration. It's very simple for the JVM to optimize into very tight native code if it needs to invoke the JIT compiler.